# how to use sqllite db in visual basic 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sqlite, database-connection, visual-studio-express

i found [this](http://www.tsjensen.com/blog/post/2011/06/04/SQLite+On+Visual+Studio+2010+Setup+Instructions.aspx) tut in the web:

and i folowed the steps but when i try to add the db in visual basic but i get this :

[image]

and when i clic in ok i get this:

[image]

can any one tell me what i did wrong? and how can i fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5561399/656243

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you are using VS express edition:**

http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/faq.wiki

> The design-time components are no longer supported for the Express
>   editions due to licensing restrictions.

check this forum thread :[Using SQLite with Visual Basic 2010 Express](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/p/2709/10231.aspx)

**otherwise:**

You need to install [ADO.NET 2.0 Provider for SQLite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlite-dotnet2/?source=directory) and check "install designer component option" when you install System.Data.SQLite

[image: Sql Lite]

Ones you install above, when you add data source select "System.Data.SQLite Database File (.NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite)"

[image: add connection]

click on new button and ones you done. check connection using "test connection" button.

Comment: @user1341926 change data source as *System.Data.SQLite Database File (.NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite)*

Comment: i dont get System.Data.SQLite Database File (.NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite) data source

Comment: @user1341926 are you using express edition? please check my updated answer

Comment: according to faq design-time components not supported for express editions